# Huge latency between two Ubuntu computers in the same wifi network

Tags: 16.04, networking, wireless, atheros

I have a strange problem. I have a laptop and a PC connected to the same wifi, running Ubtunu 16.04 and the latency is very high, sometimes it even stays around 300 ms, but it also has a high jitter. The strange part is that the latency is less than a millisecond if I run Windows 10 on that PC (laptop still running Ubuntu).

I tried to run a trick I googled,

```
sudo iwconfig wlp3s0 power off
```

but it did not help (the wifi device's name is really wlp3s0). The hardware used is (according to lspci) Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 32).

If I use a RJ45 wire to connect the two machines, it runs without issues. The latency to servers outside the local network is far from being that bad.

It makes file transfer really annoying and synergy unusable.

Any idea what might be causing this?

EDIT: More info:
What I from iwlist scanning:

```
Cell 01 - Address: 90:5C:44:A0:F7:B1
                Channel:112
                Frequency:5.56 GHz (Channel 112)
                Quality=56/70  Signal level=-54 dBm  
                Encryption key:on
                ESSID:"DugiNet Premium"
                Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s
                          36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                Mode:Master
                Extra:tsf=0000030ca45f5bbb
                Extra: Last beacon: 33488ms ago
```

Comment: Are you using 2.4ghz or 5ghz? First, make sure that you're using WPA2-AES. Then, if you're using 2.4ghz, switch your wireless channel from auto, to 1 or 6 or 11, and see if that helps. Try each one. Report back.

Comment: I am getting that channel is 112, frequency 5.56 GHz. I am not sure if I am using WPA2-AES (it is some WPA2 for sure), but that is a setting of the router and the laptop's wireless is okay. I could not change the channel, it reports that SET failed, because the device was busy (using sudo iwconfig wlp3s0 channel 1).

Comment: No, I'm sorry. The changes that I suggest are in the router. If you're using 5ghz, try channel 40. Also, understand the 5ghz will not reach as far as 2.4ghz. Report back.

Comment: It works fine on Windows 10 on the PC or on the laptop. I thought this was a driver issue. I need to find the router's manual to connect to it, it will take some time.

Comment: Is Windows using the same freq/channel? Windows does things a little differently, so it's hard to compare. To get to the router, just go to the router's address in your web browser... typically `http://192.168.0.1` or `http://192.168.1.1`.

Comment: I set the 5 GHz channel to 40 and set the 2.4 GHz one to channel 11. No change. Still no lag between the laptop Ubuntu and the Windows 10 on PC. And the security is WPA2-AES.

Comment: Darn, actually the latency now appeared also between Windows 10 and Ubuntu.

Comment: Back up. Do you have latency between two computers, one running Windows and one running Ubuntu, or something else? What channel are you connecting to now? How are you determining latency? What if you ping your router?

Comment: The latency to router is all right. Always been like that. I switched back both 5 GHz and 2.4 GHz to auto and the latency on Windows 10 is still there.

Comment: You didn't answer any of my last questions... and I'm confused about the problem you're seeing, 'cause I'm unclear about your configuration and between what and what the problem is?

Comment: Aha, so the latency between the two computers is very high, now regardless if the other one running Ubuntu or Windows 10. Hundreds of ms. Ping to router is several milliseconds from both. The laptop can be pinged, the PC cannot, regardless of the OS running. The security is WPA2-PSK.

Comment: You're still not being concise. So let me ask some questions differently... What channel is each machine connecting to? Both machines have low ping rate to the router? You can't ping the PC from where... the laptop or the router? Are your 2.4 and 5ghz networks named the same? Please answer ALL questions concisely.

Comment: The laptop is normally connected to 2.462 GHz, channel 11. The PC lists a lot of networks available when I use iwlist scanning, including both 5.56 GHz channel 112 and 2.462 GHz channel 11. I have pinged each computer both from the router and from the other computer. In both cases, the laptop was accessible, but the PC was not.

Comment: If your wireless networks are named the same, rename one of them. Then connect BOTH laptop and PC to the SAME wireless network, and retest. Report back.

Comment: It did not allow me to rename them, so I turned off the 5.56 GHz one. Now I can ping the PC (both from the router and from the laptop) and it is much better. No more random disconnections between the two, but the latency still stays in tens of milliseconds. The problem is partially solved.

Comment: How many "tens" of ms? Can you run Synergy now? What brand router?

Comment: With tens of ms, I mean that it's sometimes 2ms, sometimes 60 ms, but it rarely goes above 100 ms. Anyway, synergy makes no visible lag most of the time and does not disconnect. File transfer between the two seems to be okay too. It's possible that it can't be better at all. It's possible that the problem was just that the PC was jumping between the two wifi networks. Write an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I've done an answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments...

The subject line indicates that two computers *on the same network* have high latency and can't run Synergy. This isn't exactly accurate, as the laptop was connecting to the 2.4ghz network, and the PC was connecting to the 5ghz network. Ping times between computers was ~300ms. Ping times from either the laptop or the PC to the router were fine. The PC could not be pinged when connected to the 5ghz network.

Once the laptop and the PC were both connected to the 2.4ghz network, ping times came down to 2-60ms, and Synergy worked fine. The PC could now be pinged. **To continue testing in this configuration, the router needs to be changed from auto to either channel 1/6/11 and retested with each setting change.** Use ping times to determine performance.

The 2.4ghz and 5ghz networks need to have different names.

For now, if the laptop can do 5ghz, then connect both computers to the same 2.4ghz or 5ghz network. Later testing with laptop/PC on **different** wireless networks is going to require tweeking the VLAN/BR0 settings in the router.